# Joomla 4, Error: Class '...\Component\...\Administrator\Model\SimpleXMLElement' not found

Tags: custom-component, joomla-4.x, xml, joomla-4, php7

Please tell me what the problem may be. I adapt the component for Joomla 4. I get this error, although everything should work.

```
Class '....\Component\....\Administrator\Model\SimpleXMLElement' not found
```

Comment: I see your error message, but I don't know what you did to "adapt the component for Joomla 4".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. It was necessary to put a slash.

```
$elements = new \SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```